# What PHP framework is most similar to Apache Wicket?

Tags: java, php, frameworks, web-applications, wicket

Feature I'm looking for is being component based but not event driven.

I also like the idea of defining component in his parent code but describing its placement and some visual aspects in the template of his parent.

Answer (score 1):

On the [wicket mailing list](http://www.mail-archive.com/users@wicket.apache.org/msg36929.html) they suggest the [symfony framework](http://www.symfony-project.org/) which should be the closest thing in php world to wicket.